# Lempel-Ziv-Welch algorithm

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

Heys guys,

I'm trying to implement the Lempel-Ziv-Welch algorithm on byte level in VB.NET. Here is what the Code looks like so far:

```
        Dim FileBytes As Byte() = {Convert.ToByte(12), Convert.ToByte(13), Convert.ToByte(12), Convert.ToByte(13), Convert.ToByte(12), Convert.ToByte(13)}
    Dim bw As New BitWriter(New BinaryWriter(New FileStream(output, FileMode.Create)))
    Dim ByteDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Byte(), Integer)

    Dim DictionaryN As Integer = 1
    Dim DictionaryMax As Integer = 4048
    Dim outputs As New List(Of Integer)


    Dim bts As New List(Of Byte)
    For index As Integer = 0 To FileBytes.Length - 1
        Dim currentbyte As Byte = FileBytes(index)

        If ContainsByte(ByteDictionary, AddToList(bts, currentbyte).ToArray) Then
            bts.Add(currentbyte)
        Else

            If bts.Count > 1 Then
                ByteDictionary.Add(bts.ToArray, 255 + DictionaryN)
                DictionaryN += 1
            Else
                ByteDictionary.Add(New Byte() {currentbyte}, currentbyte)
            End If

            Console.WriteLine(GetByteValue(ByteDictionary, bts.ToArray))
            bts.Clear()
            bts.Add(currentbyte)

        End If

    Next

End Sub
Public Function ContainsByte(ByVal dic As Dictionary(Of Byte(), Integer), ByVal bt As Byte()) As Boolean
    Dim flag = True
    For Each kp As KeyValuePair(Of Byte(), Integer) In dic

        If ByteArrayEquals(kp.Key, bt) Then
            Return True
        End If

    Next
    Return False
End Function
Public Function AddToList(ByVal list As List(Of Byte), ByVal bt As Byte) As List(Of Byte)
    Dim newlist = New List(Of Byte)(list)
    newlist.Add(bt)
    Return newlist
End Function
Public Function ByteArrayEquals(ByVal first As Byte(), ByVal second As Byte()) As Boolean
    If first.Length = second.Length Then
        Dim flag = True
        For index As Integer = 0 To first.Length - 1
            If first(index) <> second(index) Then
                flag = False
            End If
        Next
        Return flag
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function


Public Function GetByteValue(ByVal dic As Dictionary(Of Byte(), Integer), ByVal bt As Byte()) As Integer
    For Each kp As KeyValuePair(Of Byte(), Integer) In dic

        If ByteArrayEquals(kp.Key, bt) Then
            Return kp.Value
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

The idea behind my implementation is from https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Multimedia/node214.html . But somehow it doesn't work, it simply puts out the input bytes. What is wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know thats why I asked :) and also the not-branch adds it to the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is these two lines:

```
        If bts.Count > 1 Then
            ByteDictionary.Add(bts.ToArray, 255 + DictionaryN)
```

In both lines here you're using `bts` where you should be using `bts` + `currentByte`, i.e. you want something like

```
    Dim currentbyte As Byte = FileBytes(index)
    Dim btsPlusCurrentByte As List(Of Byte) = AddToList(bts, currentbyte)

    If ContainsByte(ByteDictionary, btsPlusCurrentByte.ToArray) Then
        bts.Add(currentbyte)
    Else
        If btsPlusCurrentByte.Count > 1 Then
            ByteDictionary.Add(btsPlusCurrentByte.ToArray, 255 + DictionaryN)
```

The other problem is that you'll complete the loop with data left in `bts` that you haven't output, so I think you'll need a block to do that afterwards. It may be safe to just do

```
Console.WriteLine(GetByteValue(ByteDictionary, bts.ToArray))
```

again after the `Next` but I haven't thought about that very carefully.

I also think you should be able to use .NET's own built-ins rather than your four helper functions.